# How to query a field explicitly and get all possible results? Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

If you had a collection as such.

```
   user {
name: String,
email: String,
information: String
}
```

You would do something like so to get a list of all John's that have information of doctor.

```
db.user.find({name: "John", information: "doctor" });
```

Now this makes the code redundant when having variable inputs. Such as having permutations of fields to filter. I'm trying to make my query generic, such as this bad broken example.
Therefore I might want to be able to explicitly state fields that can match any value. The following examples should return the same documents in theory.

Example:

Un-Explicit (normal) `db.user.find({});`

Explicit (weird) `db.user.find({name: {$ANY}});`

Or make it even more complex.

```
db.user.find({name: {$ANY}, information: "doctor"});
```

This would not work, but the intention is to get all the documents that are doctors but have ANY sort of value on the `name` field, not just for John's. Maybe even something more complex like so.

```
db.user.find({name: function(){
  if(req.query.name)//check if empty
  { return req.query.name; }
  else { return $ANY; }
 }, information: "doctor"});
```

This would then be generic enough to use a single query instance for dynamic request behavior.As far as I know there isn't anything like this implemented.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the documents that are doctors but have **ANY** sort of value on the `name` field, you need the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) and [**`$ne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne) operators in your query, since the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null and the [**`$ne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne) operator selects the documents where the `name` field is not null:

```
db.user.find({"name": { "$exists": true, "$ne": null }, "information": "doctor"});
```

Comment: Now try to generalize that from '' (empty string) to any matching string as it would normally do, all in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the documents with `information` = 'doctor', why not just query without the name?

```
db.user.find({information: "doctor" });
```

Comment: That's where it stops being explicit.